# Select two columns at filter - vba

Tags: excel, vba

I have code which is filtering a table and starts at the first visible row of column 16241 and selects down until a cell is blank, but I am unable to select the just second column with my first column.

Please help me with this issue, I'm trying to learn VBA in excel

```
Sub PasteSpecial()

    Range("K5:L10000").Select
    Selection.ClearContents
    Selection.Borders.LineStyle = xlNone
    Range("K4").Select
    Sheets("Databeta").Visible = True
    Sheets("Databeta").Select
    Range("WZQ3").Select
    Selection.AutoFilter Field:=1, Criteria1:="<>-"

    With ActiveSheet.AutoFilter.Range

        fRow = .Offset(1).Resize(.Rows.Count - 1, _
                                 .Columns.Count) _
                         .SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).Row

    End With
    'unable to select both column

    Cells(fRow, 16241).Select

    Range(Selection, Selection.End(xlDown)).Copy
    Sheets("Variation").Select
    Range("K5").Select
    Selection.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues
    Selection.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteFormats
    Sheets("Databeta").Select
    Application.CutCopyMode = False
    ActiveSheet.ShowAllData
    Sheets("Databeta").Visible = xlVeryHidden
    Sheets("Variation").Select
    Range("D4").Select

End Sub
```

Comment: You have over 16000 columns in an Excel worksheet??!

Comment: Not sure what your code is supposed to do (looks like tweaked-up macro recorder code), but if you need to select 2 columns you should select a `Range` (like `Range("WZQ:WZR").EntireColumn.Select`) instead of a specific cell (if `Cells(fRow, 16241).Select` is where you're trying your selection?)

Comment: I have a table of 138 columns and i just want to filter by "<>-" and select from first visible row to last visible row after filtering the table....... and select only two column from the first column (my first column at 16241).